# Rake test:units fails with status(1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through agile web development with rails and I'm running into a snag when running `rake test:units`.

I'm running this on Windows 7, I can't tell if it's a problem with my install, or if I'm stuffing up something with the tests.

Here is the full trace:

```
C:/Users/tom/projects/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:5:in `<class:ProductTest>': undefined method `assert' for ProductTest:Class (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/tom/projects/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib;test" -I"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
PS C:\Users\tom\projects\depot> rake test:units --trace
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
    SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
    This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
    provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
    cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
    future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

    Called from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
C:/Users/tom/projects/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:5:in `<class:ProductTest>': undefined method `assert' for ProductTest:Class (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/tom/projects/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib;test" -I"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib"         "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/testtask.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `sh'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `ruby'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:61:in `verbose'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/testtask.rb:98:in `block in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:units
```

Edit: The test looks like this. Adding `require test/unit` didn't fix the issue.

require 'test_helper'

```
class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  product = Product.new
  assert product.invalid?
  assert product.errors[:title].any?
  assert product.errors[:description].any?
  assert product.errors[:price].any?
  assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
end
```

Comment: So what does the test look like?

Comment: Updated to include the test @FrederickCheung.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong: you must put assertions inside actuals tests, for example

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "products should do bar" do
    assert ...
  end

  test "product should do foo" do
    ...
  end
end
```